# What is the purpose of voids near thermal pad in a MOSFET?

Tags: power, mosfet, surface-mount, thermal, powermosfet

http://www.aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AONP36336.pdf

Why do MOSEFT manufacturers provide a void as shown below?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

It's called a wettable flank to make the soldered joint easier to inspect.  If part of the pad reaches the side, a correctly soldered joint with enough paste that reflows correctly will develop a little fillet on the exposed side.  See figure 5 for "side wall plated": https://www.st.com/resource/en/technical_note/dm00298756-leadless-packages-with-enhanced-board-level-solder-joint-reliability-for-automotive-application-stmicroelectronics.pdf